# don't show hidden table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem I am trying to fix.

[image]

Basically I have a jquery which active the hidden form when you click on the "send" button. The quantity and "colour" and "size"(sorry miss this in the diagram) as a both server and client side validation. My problem is that if someone used a developer tool and checked the size to something stupid like `<option value="0000000000000">size 10</option>` and click on "send" the hidden form will come visible and the total price will be `$NAN`.

**Whats in the hidden form**

the hidden form is basically a total which just slide down to show the user what the added and the total price. This uses jQuery to send the size+quantity and `price*quantity`. So if you mess up the size. the price will come up as `$NAN`.

I have manage to stop this from getting send to the cart page now I want to stop the hidden form from show.

JQUERY which activate the hidden form and also add to cart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var len = $('#size option:selected').text();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var qty = parseInt($('#Qty').val());
        var price =  parseFloat($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
        price = '\u00A3' + price.toFixed(2);
        var category = $('#Category').val();

        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // validation for quanity
        }

        else {
        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#scategory').text(cat);
        $('#slength').text(len);
        $('#selected').slideDown();
        }// this activate the hidden form


       $.ajax({
            url: 'addtocart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid:pid, 
            length:length, 
            Qty:Qty, 
            Category:Category },
            success: function(data)
            {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please if I am not making sense please tell me.

Comment: Just do an if to check that the value is reasonable before sliding down the `#selected` element.

Comment: [Real EXample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BOYDm.png) in that link you can see what I mean. How the price in this is reasonable but if I was to check the value of the side to 000000 or 0000 basically a value that is not in the database. then the price will come up as `Price: £NAN`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker please can you show an example please. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the point of this... If the user uses the inspector, he could also display the hidden form even if he didn't click the button

Comment: @Brewal that's true but the hidden form will only have `"ITEM ADDED TO BAG"` and `"price:"`. Thats it. I just want to tell users that their item has been added and the total price.

Comment: Or we could even directly send a post request to `addtocart.php` with the `pid`, `length`, etc... As long as your application is safe, you shouldn't mind about an ugly NaN displaying because the user changed the client side code.

Comment: I agree with Brewal – there doesn’t even seem to be any _real_ “problem” here.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the correctness of the values.  Here we are using price but it could be whatever you want.

Javascript:

```
if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // validation for quanity
} else {
  if( price >100 && price < 0){ 
    //don't do anything
  } else {
    $('#sprice').text(price);
    $('#scategory').text(cat);
    $('#slength').text(len);
    $('#selected').slideDown();
}
```